# Definition of binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I have this problem that I am a bit unsure about how to proceed forward with.

Problem:
Show that $n{\binom{m+n}{m} = (m+1)\binom{m+n}{m+1}}$ for all integers n, m > 0.

In the solution it says that we should use the **definition of binomial coefficient**.

Can anyone describe or tell me how to proceed with this problem ?

Comment: First write the definition of the binomial coefficient.

Comment: Is there a typo in your question?

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. $n\binom{n+n}{m} = n\frac{2n(2n-1)\dots(2n-m+1)}{m!}$, while $(m+1)\binom{m+n}{m+1} = (m+1)\frac{(m+n)(m+n-1)\dots(m+n-(m+1)+1)}{(m+1)!} = \frac{(m+n)(m+n-1)\dots n}{m!}$.

Comment: I think $n\binom{n+n}m$ should read $n\binom{m+n}m$ but will await confirmation by OP.

Comment: Sorry.. It should be m+n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
n\binom{m+n}m
&=n\frac{(m+n)!}{m!\ n!}\\
&=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!\ (n-1)!}\\
&=\color{blue}{(m+1)}\frac{(m+n)!}{\color{blue}{(m+1)}\ m!\ (n-1)!}\\
&=(m+1)\frac{(m+n)!}{(m+1)!\ (n-1)!}\\
&=(m+1)\binom{m+n}{m+1}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: The third step, how did you get that ?
$(m+1)\frac{(m+n)!}{(m+1)!\ (n-1)!}$

Comment: Is it because $(m+1)! = (m+1)*m*(m-1)*(m-2)....$ ?

Comment: See edited answer. And $(m+1)!=(m+1)m!$.

Comment: Ahh..thank you hypergeometric, well explained :)

Comment: You're most welcome :)